# What is the cardinality of $\omega^\alpha\cdot n+1$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How could I determine the cardinality of $\omega^\alpha\cdot n+1$? where $\alpha$ is an ordinal.

I think that, if $\alpha$ is infinite then $|\omega^\alpha\cdot n+1|>\aleph_0$, Is that right?

Comment: If that’s ordinal exponentiation, then then $\omega^\alpha\cdot n+1<\omega_1$ for all $\alpha<\omega_1$, and therefore $\omega^\alpha\cdot n+1$ is countable for all $\alpha<\omega_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\alpha < \omega_1$ then $\omega^{\alpha} < \omega_1$, so certainly $\omega^{\alpha} \cdot n + 1 < \omega_1$ and so $|\omega^{\alpha} \cdot n + 1| < \aleph_1$.

You can prove that $\omega^{\alpha} < \omega_1$ for all $\alpha < \omega_1$ by transfinite induction on $\alpha$.

Clearly it's true when $\alpha=0$, and if it's true for $\omega^{\alpha}$ then it's true for $\omega^{\alpha+1} = \omega^{\alpha} \cdot \omega$.

Now suppose $\alpha < \omega_1$ is a limit and $\omega^{\beta}$ is countable for all $\beta < \alpha$. Then
$$|\omega^{\alpha}| = \left| \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \omega^{\beta}\right| \le \sum_{\beta < \alpha} |\omega^{\beta}| \le |\alpha| \cdot \sup_{\beta < \alpha} |\omega^{\beta}| = \aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$$

However $|\omega^{\omega_1}| > \aleph_0$ because there is an injection $\omega_1 \to \omega^{\omega_1}$ sending $\alpha < \omega_1$ to the function $f_{\alpha} \in \omega^{\omega_1}$ defined by $f_{\alpha}(\alpha) = 1$ and $f_{\alpha}(\beta) = 0$ for $\alpha \ne \beta < \omega_1$.

A generalisation of the above arguments allows you to prove that $|\omega^{\alpha}| = |\alpha|$ for all $\alpha \ge \omega$.